# Failed to find a presenting view controller - UIDatePicker in overlay

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, datepicker

I'm presenting an overlay view using the following code (by adding it as a subview to the `window`):

```
@objc func show() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        setupBlackView(window: window)
        setupSelf(window: window)
        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(self)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
            if let height = self.percentageHeight {
                self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (1-height) * window.frame.height, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight * height)
            }
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The overlay view contains a `UIDatePicker`. This code used to work fine. However, now I am seeing the following error:

```
[Assert] Failed to find a presenting view controller for view (<_UIDatePickerIOSCompactView: 0x7fe8003288e0; frame = (0 0; 114 188.333); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003bca3d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003025a80>>) in window (<UIWindow: 0x7fe7fc436010; frame = (0 0; 390 844); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000038918f0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x60000367d5c0>>). The interaction's view (or an ancestor) must have an associated view controller for presentation to work.
```

and the `UIDatePicker` looks broken:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 14 introduced the UIDatePicker instance properties datePickerStyle {get} and preferredDatePickerStyle {set get}.  Your "broken" UIDatePicker appears to be one of the new styles.  If you're expecting the "wheel" appearance, try setting the perferredDatePickerStyle property to UIDatePickerStyle.wheels.  This may account for your error since a date picker compact view would be associated with the UTDatePickerStyle.compact style.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to build a DatePicker control that you can use everywhere in your application. What you can do is,

1. Create a derived class from UIWindow with higher Z-index, Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowlevel?language=objc)

2. Create a derived class from UIViewController and add your datePicker control on with whatever UI customisations you like.
3. Next make the view controller you created in point no.2 as rootViewController of the window you created in point no.1
4. And now, make your window as keyWindow every time you want to show the datePicker. Since UIWindow is inherited from UIView class animate it the way you want and your awesome animating DatePicker is built from scratch.

P.S you can publish that as a CocoaPod as well. ;)